# Outputting programs in the Windows system tray with AutoIT

Tags: windows, autoit

is there a way to use AutoIT to display which programs are currently running or displayed in the Windows system tray?

I have already consulted some AI tools and looked in the AutoIt documentation but can only find the possibility to run my own program in the tray

Answer (score 1):

try this to get it done. https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/103871-_systray-udf/

Your code

```
#NoTrayIcon
#include <SysTrayUDF13.au3>
#include <Process.au3>

$count = _SysTrayIconCount()
ConsoleWrite("Count visible tray:  " & $count & @CRLF)
For $i = $count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    $handle = _SysTrayIconHandle($i)
    $visible = _SysTrayIconVisible($i)
    $pid = WinGetProcess($handle)
    $name = _ProcessGetName($pid)
    $title = WinGetTitle($handle)
    $tooltip = _SysTrayIconTooltip($i)
    ConsoleWrite("index:  " & $i & @TAB & "visible:  " & $visible & @TAB & "handle:  " & $handle & @TAB & "pid:  " & _
                    $pid & @TAB & "proc:  " & $name & @TAB & @TAB & "title:  " & $title & @TAB & @TAB & "tooltip:  " & $tooltip & @CRLF)
    If $pid = -1 Then _SysTrayIconRemove($i)
Next

If _FindTrayToolbarWindow(2) <> -1 Then
    ConsoleWrite("-====================-" & @CRLF)
    $countwin7 = _SysTrayIconCount(2)
    ConsoleWrite("Count overflow area:  " & $countwin7 & @CRLF)
    For $i = $countwin7 - 1 To 0 Step -1
        $handle = _SysTrayIconHandle($i, 2)
        $visible = _SysTrayIconVisible($i, 2)
        $pid = WinGetProcess($handle)
        $name = _ProcessGetName($pid)
        $title = WinGetTitle($handle)
        $tooltip = _SysTrayIconTooltip($i, 2)
        ConsoleWrite("index:  " & $i & @TAB & "visible:  " & $visible & @TAB & "handle:  " & $handle & @TAB & "pid:  " & _
                        $pid & @TAB & "proc:  " & $name & @TAB & @TAB & "title:  " & $title & @TAB & @TAB & "tooltip:  " & $tooltip & @CRLF)
        If $pid = -1 Then _SysTrayIconRemove($i, 2)
    Next
EndIf
```

UDF

```
#include-once
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;
; Author:         Tuape
; Modified:       Erik Pilsits
;
; Script Function:
;   Systray UDF - Functions for reading icon info from system tray / removing
;   any icon.
;
; Last Update: 5/13/2013
;
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayIconCount($iWin = 1)
; Description:      Returns number of icons on systray
;                   Note: Hidden icons are also reported
; Parameter(s):     $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
;
; Requirement(s):
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns number of icons found
;                   On Failure - Returns -1
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayIconCount($iWin = 1)
    Local Const $TB_BUTTONCOUNT = 1048
    Local $hWnd = _FindTrayToolbarWindow($iWin)
    If $hWnd = -1 Then Return -1
    Local $count = DllCall("user32.dll", "lresult", "SendMessageW", "hwnd", $hWnd, "uint", $TB_BUTTONCOUNT, "wparam", 0, "lparam", 0)
    If @error Then Return -1
    Return $count[0]
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayIconCount

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayIconTitles($iWin = 1)
; Description:      Get list of all window titles that have systray icon
; Parameter(s):     $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
; Requirement(s):
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns an array with all window titles
;                   On Failure - Returns -1
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayIconTitles($iWin = 1)
    Local $count = _SysTrayIconCount($iWin)
    If $count <= 0 Then Return -1
    Local $titles[$count]
    ; Get icon owner window"s title
    For $i = 0 To $count - 1
        $titles[$i] = WinGetTitle(_SysTrayIconHandle($i, $iWin))
    Next
    Return $titles
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayIconTitles

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayIconPids($iWin = 1)
; Description:      Get list of all processes id's that have systray icon
; Parameter(s):     $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
; Requirement(s):
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns an array with all process id's
;                   On Failure - Returns -1
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayIconPids($iWin = 1)
    Local $count = _SysTrayIconCount($iWin)
    If $count <= 0 Then Return -1
    Local $processes[$count]
    For $i = 0 To $count - 1
        $processes[$i] = WinGetProcess(_SysTrayIconHandle($i, $iWin))
    Next
    Return $processes
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayIconPids

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayIconProcesses($iWin = 1)
; Description:      Get list of all processes that have systray icon
; Parameter(s):     $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
; Requirement(s):
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns an array with all process names
;                   On Failure - Returns -1
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayIconProcesses($iWin = 1)
    Local $pids = _SysTrayIconPids($iWin)
    If Not IsArray($pids) Then Return -1
    Local $processes[UBound($pids)]
    ; List all processes
    Local $list = ProcessList()
    For $i = 0 To UBound($pids) - 1
        For $j = 1 To $list[0][0]
            If $pids[$i] = $list[$j][1] Then
                $processes[$i] = $list[$j][0]
                ExitLoop
            EndIf
        Next
    Next
    Return $processes
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayIconProcesses

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayIconIndex($test, $mode = 0, $iWin = 1)
; Description:      Get list of all processes id"s that have systray icon
; Parameter(s):     $test       - process name / window title text / process PID
;                   $mode
;                   | 0         - get index by process name (default)
;                   | 1         - get index by window title
;                   | 2         - get index by process PID
;                   $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
; Requirement(s):
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns index of found icon
;                   On Failure - Returns -1
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayIconIndex($test, $mode = 0, $iWin = 1)
    Local $ret = -1, $compare = -1
    If $mode < 0 Or $mode > 2 Or Not IsInt($mode) Then Return -1
    Switch $mode
        Case 0
            $compare = _SysTrayIconProcesses($iWin)
        Case 1
            $compare = _SysTrayIconTitles($iWin)
        Case 2
            $compare = _SysTrayIconPids($iWin)
    EndSwitch
    If Not IsArray($compare) Then Return -1
    For $i = 0 To UBound($compare) - 1
        If $compare[$i] = $test Then
            $ret = $i
            ExitLoop
        EndIf
    Next
    Return $ret
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayIconIndex

; INTERNAL =====================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayGetButtonInfo($iIndex, $iWin = 1, $iInfo = 0)
; Description:      Gets Tray Button Info
; Parameter(s):     $iIndex     - icon index (Note: starting from 0)
;                   $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
;                   $iInfo      - Info to return
;                   | 1         - TBBUTTON structure
;                   | 2         - TRAYDATA structure
;                   | 3         - tooltip
;                   | 4         - icon position
; Requirement(s):
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns requested info
;                   On Failure - Sets @error and returns -1
;                   | 1        - Failed to find tray window
;                   | 2        - Failed to get tray window PID
;                   | 3        - Failed to open process
;                   | 4        - Failed to allocate memory
;                   | 5        - Failed to get TBBUTTON info
;
; Author(s):        Erik Pilsits, Tuape
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayGetButtonInfo($iIndex, $iWin = 1, $iInfo = 1)
    Local Const $TB_GETBUTTON = 1047
;~  Local Const $TB_GETBUTTONTEXT = 1099
;~  Local Const $TB_GETBUTTONINFO = 1089
    Local Const $TB_GETITEMRECT = 1053
    Local Const $ACCESS = BitOR(0x0008, 0x0010, 0x0400) ; VM_OPERATION, VM_READ, QUERY_INFORMATION
    Local $TBBUTTON
    If @OSArch = "X86" Then
        $TBBUTTON = DllStructCreate("int iBitmap;int idCommand;byte fsState;byte fsStyle;byte bReserved[2];dword dwData;int iString")
    Else ; X64
        $TBBUTTON = DllStructCreate("int iBitmap;int idCommand;byte fsState;byte fsStyle;byte bReserved[6];uint64 dwData;int64 iString")
    EndIf
    Local $TRAYDATA
    If @OSArch = "X86" Then
        $TRAYDATA = DllStructCreate("hwnd hwnd;uint uID;uint uCallbackMessage;dword Reserved[2];handle hIcon")
    Else
        $TRAYDATA = DllStructCreate("uint64 hwnd;uint uID;uint uCallbackMessage;dword Reserved[2];uint64 hIcon")
    EndIf
    Local $trayHwnd = _FindTrayToolbarWindow($iWin)
    If $trayHwnd = -1 Then Return SetError(1, 0, -1)
    Local $return, $err = 0
    Local $ret = DllCall("user32.dll", "dword", "GetWindowThreadProcessId", "hwnd", $trayHwnd, "dword*", 0)
    If @error Or Not $ret[2] Then SetError(2, 0, -1)
    Local $pId = $ret[2]
    Local $procHandle = DllCall("kernel32.dll", "handle", "OpenProcess", "dword", $ACCESS, "bool", False, "dword", $pId)
    If @error Or Not $procHandle[0] Then Return SetError(3, 0, -1)
    Local $lpData = DllCall("kernel32.dll", "ptr", "VirtualAllocEx", "handle", $procHandle[0], "ptr", 0, "ulong", DllStructGetSize($TBBUTTON), "dword", 0x1000, "dword", 0x04)
    If Not @error And $lpData[0] Then
        $ret = DllCall("user32.dll", "lresult", "SendMessageW", "hwnd", $trayHwnd, "uint", $TB_GETBUTTON, "wparam", $iIndex, "lparam", $lpData[0])
        If Not @error And $ret[0] Then
            DllCall("kernel32.dll", "bool", "ReadProcessMemory", "handle", $procHandle[0], "ptr", $lpData[0], "struct*", $TBBUTTON, "ulong", DllStructGetSize($TBBUTTON), "ulong*", 0)
            Switch $iInfo
                Case 2
                    ; TRAYDATA structure
                    DllCall("kernel32.dll", "bool", "ReadProcessMemory", "handle", $procHandle[0], "ptr", DllStructGetData($TBBUTTON, 6), "struct*", $TRAYDATA, "ulong", DllStructGetSize($TRAYDATA), "ulong*", 0)
                    $return = $TRAYDATA
                Case 3
                    ; tooltip
                    $return = ""
                    If BitShift(DllStructGetData($TBBUTTON, 7), 16) <> 0 Then
                        Local $intTip = DllStructCreate("wchar[1024]")
                        ; we have a pointer to a string, otherwise it is an internal resource identifier
                        DllCall("kernel32.dll", "bool", "ReadProcessMemory", "handle", $procHandle[0], "ptr", DllStructGetData($TBBUTTON, 7), "struct*", $intTip, "ulong", DllStructGetSize($intTip), "ulong*", 0)
                        $return = DllStructGetData($intTip, 1)
                    ;else internal resource
                    EndIf
                Case 4
                    ; icon position
                    If Not BitAND(DllStructGetData($TBBUTTON, 3), 8) Then ; 8 = TBSTATE_HIDDEN
                        Local $pos[2], $RECT = DllStructCreate("int;int;int;int")
                        DllCall("user32.dll", "lresult", "SendMessageW", "hwnd", $trayHwnd, "uint", $TB_GETITEMRECT, "wparam", $iIndex, "lparam", $lpData[0])
                        DllCall("kernel32.dll", "bool", "ReadProcessMemory", "handle", $procHandle[0], "ptr", $lpData[0], "struct*", $RECT, "ulong", DllStructGetSize($RECT), "ulong*", 0)
                        $ret = DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "MapWindowPoints", "hwnd", $trayHwnd, "ptr", 0, "struct*", $RECT, "uint", 2)
                        $pos[0] = DllStructGetData($RECT, 1)
                        $pos[1] = DllStructGetData($RECT, 2)
                        $return = $pos
                    Else
                        $return = -1
                    EndIf
                Case Else
                    ; TBBUTTON
                    $return = $TBBUTTON
            EndSwitch
        Else
            $err = 5
        EndIf
        DllCall("kernel32.dll", "bool", "VirtualFreeEx", "handle", $procHandle[0], "ptr", $lpData[0], "ulong", 0, "dword", 0x8000)
    Else
        $err = 4
    EndIf
    DllCall("kernel32.dll", "bool", "CloseHandle", "handle", $procHandle[0])
    If $err Then
        Return SetError($err, 0, -1)
    Else
        Return $return
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayGetButtonInfo

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayIconHandle($iIndex, $iWin = 1)
; Description:      Gets hwnd of window associated with systray icon of given index
; Parameter(s):     $iIndex     - icon index (Note: starting from 0)
;                   $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
;
; Requirement(s):
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns hwnd of found icon
;                   On Failure - Sets @error and returns -1
;                   | See _SysTrayGetButtonInfo for @error returns
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayIconHandle($iIndex, $iWin = 1)
    Local $TRAYDATA = _SysTrayGetButtonInfo($iIndex, $iWin, 2)
    If @error Then
        Return SetError(@error, 0, -1)
    Else
        Return Ptr(DllStructGetData($TRAYDATA, 1))
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayIconHandle

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayIconTooltip($iIndex, $iWin = 1)
; Description:      Gets the tooltip text of systray icon of given index
; Parameter(s):     $iIndex     - icon index (Note: starting from 0)
;                   $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
;
; Requirement(s):
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns tooltip text of icon
;                   On Failure - Sets @error and returns -1
;                   | See _SysTrayGetButtonInfo for @error returns
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayIconTooltip($iIndex, $iWin = 1)
    Local $ret = _SysTrayGetButtonInfo($iIndex, $iWin, 3)
    If @error Then
        Return SetError(@error, 0, -1)
    Else
        Return $ret
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayIconTooltip

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayIconPos($iIndex, $iWin = 1)
; Description:      Gets x & y position of systray icon
; Parameter(s):     $iIndex     - icon index (Note: starting from 0)
;                   $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
;
; Requirement(s):
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns array, x [0] and y [1] position of icon
;                   On Failure - Sets @error and returns -1
;                   | -1       - Icon is hidden (Autohide on XP, etc)
;                   | See _SysTrayGetButtonInfo for additional @error returns
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayIconPos($iIndex, $iWin = 1)
    Local $ret = _SysTrayGetButtonInfo($iIndex, $iWin, 4)
    If @error Then
        Return SetError(@error, 0, -1)
    Else
        If $ret = -1 Then
            Return SetError(-1, 0, -1)
        Else
            Return $ret
        EndIf
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayIconPos

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayIconVisible($iIndex, $iWin = 1)
; Description:      Gets the visibility of a systray icon
; Parameter(s):     $iIndex     - icon index (Note: starting from 0)
;                   $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
;
; Requirement(s):
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns True (visible) or False (hidden)
;                   On Failure - Sets @error and returns -1
;                   | See _SysTrayGetButtonInfo for @error returns
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayIconVisible($iIndex, $iWin = 1)
    Local $TBBUTTON = _SysTrayGetButtonInfo($iIndex, $iWin, 1)
    If @error Then
        Return SetError(@error, 0, -1)
    Else
        Return Not BitAND(DllStructGetData($TBBUTTON, 3), 8) ;TBSTATE_HIDDEN
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayIconVisible

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayIconHide($index, $iFlag, $iWin = 1)
; Description:      Hides / unhides any icon on systray
;
; Parameter(s):     $index      - icon index. Can be queried with _SysTrayIconIndex()
;                   $iFlag      - hide (1) or show (0) icon
;                   $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
;
; Requirement(s):
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns 1 if operation was successfull or 0 if
;                   icon was already hidden/unhidden
;                   On Failure - Sets @error and returns -1
;                   | See _SysTrayGetButtonInfo for @error returns
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayIconHide($index, $iFlag, $iWin = 1)
;~     Local Const $TB_HIDEBUTTON = 0x0404 ; WM_USER + 4
    Local $TBBUTTON = _SysTrayGetButtonInfo($index, $iWin, 1)
    If @error Then Return SetError(@error, 0, -1)
    Local $visible = Not BitAND(DllStructGetData($TBBUTTON, 3), 8) ;TBSTATE_HIDDEN
    If ($iFlag And Not $visible) Or (Not $iFlag And $visible) Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Local $TRAYDATA = _SysTrayGetButtonInfo($index, $iWin, 2)
        If @error Then Return SetError(@error, 0, -1)
        Local $NOTIFYICONDATA = DllStructCreate("dword cbSize;hwnd hWnd;uint uID;uint uFlags;uint uCallbackMessage;handle hIcon;wchar szTip[128];" _
            & "dword dwState;dword dwStateMask;wchar szInfo[256];uint uVersion;wchar szInfoTitle[64];dword dwInfoFlags;" _
            & "STRUCT;ulong;ushort;ushort;byte[8];ENDSTRUCT;handle hBalloonIcon")
        DllStructSetData($NOTIFYICONDATA, 1, DllStructGetSize($NOTIFYICONDATA))
        DllStructSetData($NOTIFYICONDATA, 2, Ptr(DllStructGetData($TRAYDATA, 1)))
        DllStructSetData($NOTIFYICONDATA, 3, DllStructGetData($TRAYDATA, 2))
        DllStructSetData($NOTIFYICONDATA, 4, 8) ; NIF_STATE
        DllStructSetData($NOTIFYICONDATA, 8, $iFlag) ; dw_State, 0 or 1 = NIS_HIDDEN
        DllStructSetData($NOTIFYICONDATA, 9, 1) ; dwStateMask
        Local $ret = DllCall("shell32.dll", "bool", "Shell_NotifyIconW", "dword", 0x1, "struct*", $NOTIFYICONDATA) ; NIM_MODIFY
        DllCall("user32.dll", "lresult", "SendMessageW", "hwnd", WinGetHandle("[CLASS:Shell_TrayWnd]"), "uint", 0x001A, "wparam", 0, "lparam", 0) ; WM_SETTINGCHANGE
        If IsArray($ret) And $ret[0] Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return 0
        EndIf
;~      $ret = DllCall("user32.dll", "lresult", "SendMessageW", "hwnd", $trayHwnd, "uint", $TB_HIDEBUTTON, "wparam", DllStructGetData($TBBUTTON, 2), "lparam", $iHide)
;~      If @error Or Not $ret[0] Then
;~          $return = -1
;~      Else
;~          $return = $ret[0]
;~      EndIf
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayIconHide

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayIconMove($curPos, $newPos, $iWin = 1)
; Description:      Moves systray icon
;
; Parameter(s):     $curPos     - icon's current index (0 based)
;                   $newPos     - icon's new position
;                                 ($curPos+1 = one step to right, $curPos-1 = one step to left)
;                   $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
;
; Requirement(s):   AutoIt3 Beta
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns 1 if operation was successfull, 0 if not
;                   On Failure - Sets @error and returns -1
;                   | 1        - Bad parameters
;                   | 2        - Failed to find tray window
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayIconMove($curPos, $newPos, $iWin = 1)
    Local Const $TB_MOVEBUTTON = 0x0452 ; WM_USER + 82
    Local $iconCount = _SysTrayIconCount($iWin)
    If $curPos < 0 Or $newPos < 0 Or $curPos > $iconCount - 1 Or $newPos > $iconCount - 1 Or Not IsInt($curPos) Or Not IsInt($newPos) Then Return SetError(1, 0, -1)
    Local $hWnd = _FindTrayToolbarWindow($iWin)
    If $hWnd = -1 Then Return SetError(2, 0, -1)
    Local $ret = DllCall("user32.dll", "lresult", "SendMessageW", "hwnd", $hWnd, "uint", $TB_MOVEBUTTON, "wparam", $curPos, "lparam", $newPos)
    If @error Or Not $ret[0] Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Return 1
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayIconMove

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _SysTrayIconRemove($index, $iWin = 1)
; Description:      Removes systray icon completely.
;
; Parameter(s):     $index      - Icon index (first icon is 0)
;                   $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
;
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns 1 if icon successfully removed, 0 if not
;                   On Failure - Sets @error and returns -1
;                   | See _SysTrayGetButtonInfo for @error returns
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _SysTrayIconRemove($index, $iWin = 1)
    Local Const $TB_DELETEBUTTON = 1046
    Local $TRAYDATA = _SysTrayGetButtonInfo($index, $iWin, 2)
    If @error Then Return SetError(@error, 0, -1)
    Local $NOTIFYICONDATA = DllStructCreate("dword cbSize;hwnd hWnd;uint uID;uint uFlags;uint uCallbackMessage;handle hIcon;wchar szTip[128];" _
        & "dword dwState;dword dwStateMask;wchar szInfo[256];uint uVersion;wchar szInfoTitle[64];dword dwInfoFlags;" _
        & "STRUCT;ulong;ushort;ushort;byte[8];ENDSTRUCT;handle hBalloonIcon")
    DllStructSetData($NOTIFYICONDATA, 1, DllStructGetSize($NOTIFYICONDATA))
    DllStructSetData($NOTIFYICONDATA, 2, Ptr(DllStructGetData($TRAYDATA, 1)))
    DllStructSetData($NOTIFYICONDATA, 3, DllStructGetData($TRAYDATA, 2))
    Local $ret = DllCall("shell32.dll", "bool", "Shell_NotifyIconW", "dword", 0x2, "struct*", $NOTIFYICONDATA) ; NIM_DELETE
    DllCall("user32.dll", "lresult", "SendMessageW", "hwnd", WinGetHandle("[CLASS:Shell_TrayWnd]"), "uint", 0x001A, "wparam", 0, "lparam", 0) ; WM_SETTINGCHANGE
    If IsArray($ret) And $ret[0] Then
        Return 1
    Else
        Return 0
    EndIf
;~  Local $hWnd = _FindTrayToolbarWindow($iWin)
;~  If $hwnd = -1 Then Return -1
;~  Local $ret = DllCall("user32.dll", "lresult", "SendMessageW", "hwnd", $hWnd, "uint", $TB_DELETEBUTTON, "wparam", $index, "lparam", 0)
;~  If @error Or Not $ret[0] Then Return -1
;~  Return $ret[0]
EndFunc   ;==>_SysTrayIconRemove

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _FindTrayToolbarWindow($iWin = 1)
; Description:      Utility function for finding Toolbar window hwnd
; Parameter(s):     $iWin
;                   | 1         - ToolbarWindow32, Win2000+
;                   | 2         - NotifyIconOverflowWindow, Win7+
;
; Requirement(s):
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns Toolbar window hwnd
;                   On Failure - returns -1
;
; Author(s):        Tuape, Erik Pilsits
;
;===============================================================================
Func _FindTrayToolbarWindow($iWin = 1)
    Local $hwnd, $ret = -1
    If $iWin = 1 Then
        $hWnd = DllCall("user32.dll", "hwnd", "FindWindow", "str", "Shell_TrayWnd", "ptr", 0)
        If @error Then Return -1
        $hWnd = DllCall("user32.dll", "hwnd", "FindWindowEx", "hwnd", $hWnd[0], "hwnd", 0, "str", "TrayNotifyWnd", "ptr", 0)
        If @error Then Return -1
        If @OSVersion <> "WIN_2000" Then
            $hWnd = DllCall("user32.dll", "hwnd", "FindWindowEx", "hwnd", $hWnd[0], "hwnd", 0, "str", "SysPager", "ptr", 0)
            If @error Then Return -1
        EndIf
        $hWnd = DllCall("user32.dll", "hwnd", "FindWindowEx", "hwnd", $hWnd[0], "hwnd", 0, "str", "ToolbarWindow32", "ptr", 0)
        If @error Then Return -1
        $ret = $hwnd[0]
    ElseIf $iWin = 2 Then
        ; NotifyIconOverflowWindow for Windows 7
        $hWnd = DllCall("user32.dll", "hwnd", "FindWindow", "str", "NotifyIconOverflowWindow", "ptr", 0)
        If @error Then Return -1
        $hWnd = DllCall("user32.dll", "hwnd", "FindWindowEx", "hwnd", $hWnd[0], "hwnd", 0, "str", "ToolbarWindow32", "ptr", 0)
        If @error Then Return -1
        $ret = $hwnd[0]
    EndIf
    Return $ret
EndFunc   ;==>_FindTrayToolbarWindow
```